# Advance designing in the xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Sample Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INlcL.png) [Sample Image2 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n33Et.png) I am designing the given sample image in xamarin but unable to create it.
What i create is [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHOR.png)

```
<StackLayout
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="Black">
        <!-- Here I want to add half circle in middle of the stacklayout and put image here   -->
        <Image
            Source="abc.png" />
    </StackLayout>
```

I  have searched and it seem I need to use stacklayout. I tried to do that setting the both objects in the same grid (row and line 0), and then, using constraintX to set the second in the same Y with factor 0 and a negative constant...But it didn't work. The a deleted the lines and can't show here, unfortunately...the only thing that happend in this is: the both was in the same position in y, but I could do like the image above... Can someone help me with an example, idea or anything? thank you very much

Comment: You could use `Grid Layout`, this particular layout allows you to put layouts on de z-index when stack, that means if you put first an `StackLayout` and then a `BoxView` inside the Grid, the BoxView  will display over `StackLayout`

Comment: An absolute layout could also work. Take a look at the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#exploring-a-complex-layout) provided by Xamarin where they're doing almost exactly this.

Comment: @Andrew In this example they add boxview with the same color in the layout so it look like the my problem but it doesn't. I have background image and then place a stacklayout/boxview in the bottom of screen and then make a half circle in the center of it and in this circle i want to place a image or button. Thanks it also help me in other scenarios.

Comment: In your case, I think you have to draw your own bottom circle view with [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) instead of using stacklayout.